# Regex.Match() won't match a substring

Tags: c#, regex

This is something simple but I cannot figure this out. I want to find a substring with this regex. It will mach "M4N 3M5", but doesn't match the below :

```
const string text = "asdf M4N 3M5 adsf";
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}$", RegexOptions.None);
Match match = regex.Match(text);
string value = match.Value;
```

Comment: Take a look at this site: www.regular-expressions.info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try removing ^ and $:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}", RegexOptions.None);
```

- ^ : The match must start at the beginning of the string or line.
- $ : The match must occur at the end of the string or before \n at the
  end of the line or string.

If you want to match only in word boundaries you can use \b as suggested by Mike Strobel:

```
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"\b[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{1} *\d{1}[A-Z]{1}\d{1}\b", RegexOptions.None);
```

Comment: Perhaps replace them with word boundaries (`\b`)?

Comment: @fcuesta, You got it, but I thought the ^ is for starting it with one of characters specified. Still don't get why I had to do it.

Comment: If you want to match `"asdf M4N 3M5 adsf"` but not `"asdfM4N 3M5adsf"`, then you need to add `\b` to both ends of the pattern.

Comment: Also, please remove all those useless `{1}`s.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, i have mentioned this in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered but i have noticed two thing in your pattern which i want to highlight:

> 1. No need to mention the single instance of any token.
>
>    For example: (Notice the missing `{1}`)
>
>    \d{1}    = \d
>
>    [A-Z]{1} = [A-Z]
> 2. Also I won't recommend you to enter a `<space>`in your pattern use '\s' instead because if mistakenly a backspace is pressed you might not
>      be able to figure out the mistake and running code will stop
>      working.

Personally, for this case i would recommend you to use `\b` since it is best fit here.